# How to click TinyMCE toolbar's button programmatically?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to make preview button as usual form button next to submit button(as it made in most cases of  "Post new topic" forms). How can I programmatically simulate toolbar's preview button click ?

I tried `$('#article_body_preview').click()` but it didn't work. (I use jQuery lib and #article_body_preview is toolbar's preview button  element )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem myself. You can find the names of commands in the source code of plugins. Eg. for preview plugin the source code is in jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/preview/editor_plugin_src.js
Look for line #37:

```
ed.addButton('preview', {title : 'preview.preview_desc', cmd : 'mcePreview'});
```

So the command name is not 'preview' but '**mcePreview**'.

I wanted to set full screen mode on init. I ended up adding

```
init_instance_callback : 'resizeEditorBox'
```

to init.

```
resizeEditorBox = function (editor) {
            setTimeout("tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceFullScreen')", 100);
}
```

before init and commenting out:

```
//                    a.win.setTimeout(function() {
//                        tinymce.dom.Event.remove(a.win, "resize", e.resizeFunc);
//                        tinyMCE.get(c.getParam("fullscreen_editor_id")).setContent(c.getContent({format:"raw"}), {format:"raw"});
//                        tinyMCE.remove(c);
//                        a.remove("mce_fullscreen_container");
//                        i.style.overflow = c.getParam("fullscreen_html_overflow");
//                        a.setStyle(a.doc.body, "overflow", c.getParam("fullscreen_overflow"));
//                        a.win.scrollTo(c.getParam("fullscreen_scrollx"), c.getParam("fullscreen_scrolly"));
//                        tinyMCE.settings = tinyMCE.oldSettings
//                    }, 10)
```

in editor_plugin.js - because I don't need any other mode, just fullscreen mode. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but I had this same issue with tinyMCE 4, and couldn't get any of the solutions above to work. This worked for me:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.buttons.charmap.onclick();
```

So for example I was trying to create a custom menu in a plugin that included some built in commands:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myplugin', function(editor) {

    editor.addButton('mymenu', {
        type: 'menubutton',
        text: 'Insert',
        icon: false,
        menu: [
            {
                text: 'Special Character',
                icon: 'charmap',
                onclick: function() { editor.buttons.charmap.onclick(); }
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: You sir, are a saint.

Answer (score 5):

`tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('commandName');`

where `commandName` is the command registered to the preview button.

Comment: it works for some buttons, but doesn't for others. Maybe there is misunderstanding what "commandName" is. I tried tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('preview'); but it didn't do the trick. I use standard preview pluging's button

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add that I also needed to set the button active(highlighted). I used this code to accomplish this:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.setActive('spellchecker', true);
```

Replace spellchecker with the toolbar option name that you set in theme_advanced_buttons on TinyMCE init.

Cheers!

By the way, if you want to turn on a button by default, there's a forum post here that it might help you:
http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=95893#p95893

Answer (score 1):

**You can also do something like:**

```
editor.ui.registry.getAll().buttons['my-button'].onAction()
```

Full example for **my case**: *(I try to trigger without import anything)*

```
const parentTinyMCEId = 'mce_0' // When you know the target id
window.tinymce.editors.forEach(editor => { // Loop to find correct editor
  if (editor.id === tinyMCEId) {
    editor.execCommand('mceFocus', false, editor.id) // Set focus to the editor
    setTimeout(() => {
      editor.ui.registry.getAll().buttons['my-button'].onAction() // Trigger it!
    }, 100)
    return false // Stop looping
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Button creation example]

To trigger click to TinyMCE button from somewhere you want do next:

```
jQuery(".js_inpost_gallery_insert_shortcode").click(function() {
            tinyMCE.get(tinyMCE.activeEditor.editorId).controlManager.get(tinyMCE.activeEditor.editorId + "_" + 'pn_tinymce_button').settings.onclick();
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoever needs it, for Rails with capybara, to click on any plugin icon on toolbar:

```
page.execute_script("$(tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceEmoticons'))")
```

Instead of `'mceEmoticons'` can be used any other plugin, just add `'mce'` prefix and first capital letter of plugin name.